# Leer un archivo especifico

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo en stack. Soy estudiante de Python y me encuentro realizando un proyecto personal, donde intento obtener datos específicos de un archivo pdf (especificamente de facturas digitales).

De momento llevo creado un script que me funciona, pero solo para un estereotipo de comprobantes. Día a día voy agregando mas filtros para abarcar mas diseños distintos. (Esto es totalmente académico y aplicado a mi trabajo diario).

Al pie voy a dejar la ruta mi repositorio para el que este interesado pueda verlo.

Mi traba de hoy es la siguiente:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

#Leemos el pdf entero y luego usamos page para leer la pagina deseada.
reader = PdfReader("factura.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]

#Extraemos el texto del pdf
informacion = page.extract_text()

#Creamos y abre un txt en modo de escritura y pasamos todo el texto
with open ("pdf.txt", "w") as txt:
    txt.write(informacion)
```

**A la variable reader le asigne la función de PdfReader de la libreria PyPDF2. Que abra un documento .PDF que este en la ruta especificada.
Mi intención es hacer lo siguiente (Dado que los pdf van a variar de nombres):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Allí esta la ruta donde se encuentra la "factura.pdf" pero aparte hay mas con nombres distintos.

Mi intención es poder seleccionar cualquiera, soltarlo sobre el script .py y el programa ejecute todo a base del pdf que le arroje.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y finalmente el script siga corriendo todas las lineas de código a base del archivo que le asigne, es decir que la variable `reader = PdfReader("AQUI SEA EL NOMBRE DEL PDF QUE LE ARROJE!")`**

Bueno espero haber sido claro al respecto, acepto cualquier critica o sugerencia, todo sera bienvenido. Gracias !

PD: Link de mi repositorio [Mi proyecto PFACTURA by Romo64-SADOMING](https://github.com/romo64/pfactura)

Comment: Eso no es posible desde un programa basado en consola (o quizás si pero desconozco) lo mejor sería crear una GUI para todo eso

Comment: Mmm si, estube investigando al respecto de GUI pero recuerdo que una vez pude ver algo como lo que estoy consultando y de alli viene mi consulta.  Se podia obtener informacion de un archivo que "se lo tira" a un script, pero no recuerdo si estaba echo en Python o que, pero bueno todo me sirve de momento seguire investigando ! gracias Christian.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar Flask, tendrias que usar un entorno virtual pero no pasa nada... con Flask puedes hacer eso y un poco mas si ya quieres meter esa data a una base de datos [igual lo puedes hacer por consola]. Flask es liviano y le vas agregando los plugin que necesitas. Puedes elaborar batch para arrancar el servidor y poder utilizar en red.

Comment: @edsantoshn Gracias, ahora voy a comenzar a investigar flask y ver que logro resolver con ello. Si consigo avances fructiferos dejare un comentario demostrando como se resolvio.